# Is there a way to set the amount a sliders value changes when you use it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm am trying to make it so that when you interact with a slider, it goes up or down by 5. I know you can make it go up in whole numbers but can you change the base value that it increases/decreases by?

Comment: Are we talking about inspector slider or UI slider?

Comment: UI Sliders. Trying to make it so that when you use the sliders, it goes up/down by five.

Comment: @JordanWharmby, the `stepSize` field for the Slider is having `private` access, so seems like you have to make minor adjustments to your code, as suggested in the first part of the answer.

Comment: Seems like something you should just be able to edit in the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Not a built-in feature unfortunately. The workaround is to enable `Whole Numbers`, and set:

- `Slider min = Actual min / Step`
- `Slider max = Actual max / Step`

Then in your code you can do `Actual value = Slider value * Step`

Or you can write your own slider component with stepping support.

PS: I know, it sucks.